# Using numpy index for dates in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
                              Close
Date                               
2016-12-22                    11.43
2016-12-23                    11.44
2016-12-27                    11.99
2016-12-28                    12.95
2016-12-29                    13.37
```

I want just the date, not month or year, and use it as the X-Axis in a matplotlib graph.

I used

```
np.index.day
```

to extract the dates. The results look like this:

[22 23 27 28 29]

But when I use them for the X-axis in:

plt.xlim(np,5)

I get ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). np.tolist() didn't help. What would make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to extract the days from your array and then set the x-limit of a plot accordingly. You can do this with:

```
limits = np.index.day
plt.xlim(limits[0], limits[-1])
```

Your line `plt.xlim(np, 5)` doesn't make any sense, since you pass the `np` module and the integer `5` as an argument to `xlim()`.

`plt.xlim()` accepts numeric values for the minimal and maximal limit on the x-axes (see the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim)). In the above example we get the days from the `numpy` array and set the first element of the resulting array to be the minimum x-value and the last one to the maximum x-value.

---

**Update 26/01/20174:**

In case you want to plot date ranges across multiple months, it would be better to use the corresponding datetime objects and format the x-axis accordingly.

I will construct a simple example that plots data from 2016-12-29 to 2017-01-02:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.dates import DayLocator, DateFormatter

a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Date': pd.date_range('2016-12-29', '2017-01-02'), 'Close': (11.43, 11.44, 11.99, 12.95, 13.37)}).set_index('Date')
print(a)

days = DayLocator()
daysFmt = DateFormatter('%d')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot_date(a.index, a.Close)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(daysFmt)

plt.show()
```

Results:

```
            Close
Date
2016-12-29  11.43
2016-12-30  11.44
2016-12-31  11.99
2017-01-01  12.95
2017-01-02  13.37
```

[image]

Comment: I tried plt.xlim(limits[0], limits[-1]), but it fails to draw any lines. Just the X-Y axis. And the x-axis only goes from 22 to 23.

Comment: I think I understand why this isn't working. Because they are dates, they start over each month. So if the array above included 2017-1-1, the X axis thinks you're counting from 22 to 1.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example for plotting data across multiple months. I hope this answers your question now.